# Table Relations in GUI using SQL developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a connection to the database in a SQL developer. Now in there I can see lots of Table having different dependencies and constraints applied. now its very confusing and time consuming to see the details of each table manually. I want them in a way(GUI) so that I can easily Identify that particular table is master one and all the dependencies of all other tables. does it provide any kind of tool ? or is there any other Method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an ER diagram for the objects and their relations.

1. File -> Data Modeler -> Import -> Data Dictionary
2. Choose the database and schema which contains the objects.
3. Choose the objects

Comment: Thank you :) now I can see all the tables and their relation in a diagram